# Linux: Open URL from command line, then wait a specified time, then close web browser

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, command-line

I have attempted to create a script that will accomplish the following:

1. Launch the Firefox web browser with a specified URL.
2. Pause for 5 seconds (using the `timeout` command)
3. Gracefully close Firefox using `wmctrl`.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox http://www.google.com
timeout 5; DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "firefox"
```

However, after running the script, I must manually close Firefox. The timeout command does not function properly.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you want `sleep`, `timeout` is a coreutils tool which syntax is dependant of the command which you want to stop running after certain time: `timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]`.

timeout works as follow:

```
timeout 5 firefox http://www.google.com.ar
```

will close firefox in 5 seconds, but not "gracefully" as you intend, but rather sending it a `SIGTERM` (unless specified otherwise).

if you want to launch firefox, wait 5 seconds, and then proceed to close it with `wmctrl`:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox http://www.google.com
sleep 5; DISPLAY=:0.0 wmctrl -c "firefox"
```